# is there any way to connect the discord bot with a github repository?

Tags: discord.js

i was just curious to know if there is a way to do something like whenever you commit changes in a github repository, the Discord bot automatically gets to know that and it pulls the new files and restarts itself.

Comment: what host are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your host for an automatic deployment. Activate that automatic deployment.
I know Heroku has the option (I think other hosting service also have this feature) and it adds a web hook to your repo to know there is a commit then it pulls it and tries to restart it again.